# Bug in which the incorrect user was temporarily listed as the owner of a question

Tags: bug, questions

In a moderator flag on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/175843/264), as well as in the comments, some users report having temporarily seen the user Shaktal listed as the owner of the question, when in fact the question belongs to the user Chris' sister. The user Shaktal had only edited the question.

This thread will be for anyone who saw this bug to elaborate on any details that might help with its resolution, e.g. the browser and operating system being used at the time, and any screen shots that might be available.

Comment: I might have caused some confusion here: I *thought* what Zev describes above was happening, but *with the roles of Chris' sister and Shaktal switched*. In fact, this probably wasn't the case either: I came to the conclusion that Shaktal must be the actual OP by looking at the edit history and presumably just missed the bottommost entry.

Comment: It once happened to me, and when I refreshed thrice it was fixed. Someone edited one of my questions and was shown as the one who asked the question. At the time, I thought it was a browser specific issue or something like that. Chrome 20.0.1132.57, windows 7.

Comment: Just found [an evidence](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WI5Ty.jpg), though it wasn't on MSE but another SE site. That one is a question I asked but shown as that guy asked it.